# Why is the userid in the sandbox one digit less than my WhatsApp number?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

As in the title, I only found that the number in Brazil will be one less, and the number in Argentina is normal, which is very strange

[image]

However my phone number is +5531999394804, there are 3 nines in the middle instead of two 9s

I try to test Agentina whatsapp , and it is normal, I want to know why ?

Answer (score 2):

this has happened in our team as well, and I can explain why.

In 2016, Brazilian phone numbers were updated to include an additional digit 9. To accommodate this change, WhatsApp implemented a specific handling for Brazilian numbers.

It's important to note that this is not a Twilio problem, but rather a behavior of WhatsApp. If a phone number was registered on WhatsApp before the 2016, it will be displayed without the additional digit.

This behavior will not occur when sending messages to phone numbers outside of Brazil. It is likely that this treatment is exclusive inside Brazil *(my guess)*.

Comment: I got it , I'm really appreciate you